# Can we get the Jacobian of functions with vector inputs in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, documentation, autograd

My goal is to understand how to use torch.autograd.grad.

Documentation gives a description as

`torch.autograd.grad(`*`outputs`*`,` *`inputs`*`,` *`grad_outputs=None`*`,` *`retain_graph=None`*`,` *`create_graph=False`*`,` *`only_inputs=True`*`,` *`allow_unused=False`*`,` *`is_grads_batched=False`*`)`

**Computes and returns the sum of gradients of outputs with respect to the inputs.**

so I made this derivative function:

```
def derivative(y, t): 
  return torch.autograd.grad(y, t)
```

And can return gradient for y if y is scalar or sum of gradients of each component of y wrt vector t

```
def f(x):
  return (x**2).sum()

x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3],dtype = torch.float,  requires_grad = True)
derivative(f(x), x)

# returns 2*x
```

```
def f(x):
  return (x[0], x[1], x[2], x[0])

x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3],dtype = torch.float,  requires_grad = True)
derivative(f(x), x)

# returns (tensor([2., 1., 1.]),)
```

But it doesn't work for y values that are tensors in t, nor I can get the full Jacobian.

Could you show how to get gradients of tensor outputs wrt to tensor inputs or how to get Jacobian?